# YugabyteDB CDC compared to PostgreSQL logical replication

Tags: yugabytedb

I have some questions when using yugabyteDB CDC related features. I would like to know if yugabyteDB is the same as PostgreSQL, it keeps generating wal and keeps taking up storage space.

When I used postgresql, I had stopped the cdc but did not delete the replication slot in time to cause the wal to accumulate and occupy the storage, I am not sure if YugabyteDB will have the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

The storage engine is different from Postgresql: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/architecture/docdb/ .But we also have a WAL.

The equivalent of a replication slot in PG is a CDC stream. Even if the stream is NOT deleted, 4 hours of WAL is retained. Older records are deleted. Controlled by `cdc-intent-retention-ms` option: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/reference/configuration/yb-tserver/#cdc-intent-retention-ms